# Is Ubuntu developer's preview going to be installable on Nexus 10 (besides Nexus 7)?

Tags: tablet, nexus-10

[This article at arstechnica](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2013/02/ubuntu-for-tablets-arriving-on-nexus-7-nexus-10-this-week/) suggests Nexus 7 **and** Nexus 10 will be supported by upcoming Developer's preview of Ubuntu for tablets.

Is that statement backed by some Canonical's source? Is Nexus 10 going really to be supported?

Comment: Wasn't the OS demoed on a Nexus 10?

Comment: I tend to take demonstrations videos with grain of salt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Touch Developer Preview of Ubuntu will be published on the 21st
>   February 2013 with installation instructions for the **Nexus 7 and Nexus
>   10 tablet** devices as well as smartphones such as the Nexus 4 and
>   Galaxy Nexus. Installable images and source code will be available
>   from developer.ubuntu.com.

http://www.ubuntu.com/static/u/files/section/devices/Ubuntu-tablet-press-release-en.pdf